# How to avoid that a class recreates a client\session when reinstatiated on python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

let me clear my case:

I'm interacting with s3 across multiple parts of my code in python, because of that I create a class called `S3Interactor`

This is the class:

```
class S3Interactor(BaseInteractor):
    """Class that loads data into dataframes from s3

    Args:
        Loader (_type_): _description_
    """

    def __init__(self, bucket_name: str, aws_region: str):
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
        self.aws_region = aws_region
        self._s3_client = None

    @property
    def s3_client(self):
        if self._s3_client is None:
            self._s3_client = self.create_client()
        return self._s3_client

    @monitor(local_logger=logger)
    def create_client(self):
        """Create client that connects to loader interface"""
```

The problem is that this generates a bottleneck because every time that I instantiate my code this creates a session with s3 and there is some latency.

I want to have this `@property` client already set so I avoid this initial latency and just reuse that connection. I was thinking on using a Singleton but I want to know more pythonic ways.

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks

Comment: What's preventing you from instantiating your `S3Interactor` class once, and using that instance for all requests/interactions?

Comment: The way that the code is designed (legacy), this is would require a lot of effort.